# ASP.NET Templating with BasePage vs MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, uiculture

I have to deal with an ASP.NET project in which i have to support localization and translation.
Change of colture may happen only in InitializeCulture method of Page object and not on MasterPage.

Usually when i have to deal with common elements (header/footer) i put them in MasterPage but doing so prevent me to properly localize those elements.
So i am intereseted in understand how to template a page using a common base page that will be derived by all other pages (a sort of MasterPage).

I have found this article that explain clearly how to handle such situation, but i think is a bit outdated :
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2915/ASP-NET-Page-Templates-Using-Inheritance

So i would ask if there is a better approach or technology to achieve my goal.

Comment: A Master Page load AFTER the normal Page containing it. So you should be fine with the localization.

Comment: @VDWWD oh gosh I waste so many times try to work around..and do not realize this.. tomorrow I will try again keeping in mind that. Really thanks if it works it made my day tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple demo of how to send a variable to the Master Page. Put a public property in the Master named `Language`.

```
public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string Language { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = $"My language is {Language}.";
    }
}
```

Then add a property for the Master in the normal page and cast `Page.Master` to your Master Page's partial class (`Site1` by default).

```
public partial class Default1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public Site1 master;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        master = (Site1)Page.Master;
    }
```

Then you can access `Language` in the Master from the Page.

```
master.Language = "nl-NL";
```

Comment: Today i have tested a bit solution you proposed, and work perfectly.
Thanks again for help.